# CakePHP 3 correct way to modify request data in a controller

Tags: php, cakephp

There are numerous posts about this on SO but all seem out-of-date.

Using CakePHP 3.7 in 2019 and following a tutorial on implementing a "password reset" email: http://web.archive.org/web/20171001155555/http://www.naidim.org/cakephp-3-tutorial-9-reset-password

The application has a `users` table which has 2 fields called `passkey` and `timeout`. In the sample code linked above they have used the following to "unset" these 2 fields when the user is resetting their password:

```
$this->request->data['passkey'] = null;
$this->request->data['timeout'] = null;
```

It seems that this is deprecated and you cannot set request data in a controller like this anymore.

My plan was to attempt to use `array_merge()` to merge the request data and anything we want to modify like this:

```
$save_data = array_merge($this->request->getData(), ['passkey' => null, 'timeout' => null]);

// Note $user is the result of a find query done earlier.
$this->Users->patchEntity($user, $save_data);
```

Doing this seems to have no effect on the data saved in the DB - it will update the password field (which comes from a form on the linked post). But it will not modify either the `passkey` or `timeout` fields in the DB.

If I `debug($save_data)` is it indeed giving me an array of:

```
[
    'password' => 'foo',
    'confirm_password' => 'foo',
    'passkey' => null,
    'timeout' = null
];
```

Is this the wrong way to do it? I believe the reason this has been changed is to do with request objects being immutable, although it was easier programatically to be able to set data through `$this->request` as previously.

Comment: Sounds more like your question is something like "_how to `null` database columns_"!? You can still modify request data (using the `withData()` and `withoutData()` methods), but having to do that is often times indicative of a problem with your application design... I'd say that you should shift your focus on the part after that, ie patching and saving the data. For starters check what the entity looks like after patching, make sure that your columns are actually nullable, and that your model cache is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I don't really follow. If you look at the linked example the use case for this is pretty clear. When a user requests to reset their password it writes to the `passkey` and `timeout` fields in the `users` table - that works fine. But when they have performed the reset, it needs to clear those fields. So they should become `null` because there shouldn't be any data left in the fields after the reset occurs. Why is that a poor application design? If that data was left there, it would be a risk because you're leaving a key that could be used to do a password reset.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that there's something wrong with the concept of confirming a password reset request. It was just a general note that the fact that you try to modify the request object, _might_ indicate that there's something wrong with the way you're trying to solve the task. For example, if you shift things into the model layer, then you could unset the data in a custom method dedicated to password resetting (or not even accept additional data), or in a `Model.beforeSave` event, this keeps the request object untouched, and keeps your application DRY.

Comment: As for nullable: [Shim.Nullable](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/master/src/Model/Behavior/NullableBehavior.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood your needs but ensuring the passkey and timeout are reset in the reset function could be done by refactoring the linked code to the below. This may be one way...

// AS IS

```
// Clear passkey and timeout
$this->request->data['passkey'] = null;
$this->request->data['timeout'] = null;
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
…
```

// TO THIS

```
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());

// Clear passkey and timeout
$user->passkey = null;
$user->timeout = null;

if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
…
```